# How does selenium decide when a page has finished rendering?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When we use Selenium to test a page, such as using `webdriver.Firefox()` or `webdriver.Chrome()`, how does Selenium know when is the time that the page has finished rendering?

For example, if we do

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
result = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#some-data')
```

I have noticed that if a page asynchronously fetches the data (using xhr) and displays it on the page, the last line in the code above was able to find the data.

However, what is the rule that `browser.find_elements_by_css_selector()` can proceed? It can be 1 second, 2 seconds, or the page can even have a `setTimeout()` after 2 seconds to fetch some data and fill in the page (say, if it is secondary important data). So what is the determining factor that Selenium knows: the page has finished rendering and we can find elements in it now?

Comment: I believe you are talking about `pageLoadStrategy` https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/

Comment: of the 3 strategies on that page: normal, eager, none, they do not say, waiting beyond any xhr fetch... I can imagine if there is a mode that says `patient` and it can let us wait for 3 seconds or 10 seconds, or if it has a mode `waitForXHR` that says "wait for 1 second, and then wait for all existing xhr to have completed"

Answer (score 1):

If you have requests asynchronously, selenium doesn't know when it's complete. But you can wait for an element and define how long you want to wait for it.
Following the documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is `asynchronous request`

Comment: so isn't it true we can also use `time.sleep(10)` to sleep for 10 seconds if we expect the page to finish rendering in 10 seconds?  Or we can also use `time.sleep(1)` until the element exists on the page (or until the element has content in it instead of empty)

Comment: @nonopolarity We can use `sleep` but it is not recommended. You can use `explicit` wait instead. Difference between `sleep` and `explicit` is, you are trying to find an element in page A and if you use `sleep`  driver waits till 10 seconds even element appeared at 6th second but with `explicit` wait if element appeared at 6th second then driver skips remaining 4 seconds of wait.

Answer (score 1):

> Selenium knows: the page has finished rendering and we can find
> elements in it now?

Selenium WebDriver has inbuilt `pageLoadStrategy`. On launching a web page or navigating to a new page before it performs any actions it waits till `document.readyState` status changes to `Complete`

- If `pageLoadStartegy` is `NORMAL`. In this way, `WebDriver` waits till all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images loaded.

```
    setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
```

- If `pageLoadStrategy` is `EAGER`. In this way, `WebDriver` waits till `HTML` content is loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```
    setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
```

> Now there is another question for `wait` statements.

After page is loaded, we try to perform some action like  `click()` `get()` etc.  For an example, on clicking a `button` it displays a table of information in a web page within some time and we need access that information but to fetch that information it may take some time so here we can use `wait` statements.

**Code#1**: Using `time.sleep()` is not recommended.

- To fetch the information it may take around 6 seconds with this `sleep` statements driver waits till 10 seconds even data is available before the given time.
- Sometimes due to many reasons fetaching information takes more than 10 seconds in that case it fails.

```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("element").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element2").text
```

**Code#2**: Using `Implicit` wait.

- It is a global wait and applied to all elements on the webpage.
- Driver waits for 10 seconds before clicking `element` as well getting text from `element2`

```
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("element").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element2").text
```

**Code#3**: Using `Explict` wait.

- It allows the code to halt program execution, or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves for given amount of time.
- If the condition is satisfied then the remaining wait time will be aborted.
- In below code, if the text is available at 6th second then rest of the wait time will be aborted.

```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("element").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "element2")))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("element2").text
```

There are other wait functions like `FluentWait` and `setScriptTimeOut` also available.

**References**:

1. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/
2. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/